# Meanings of snatch, grab, grip, seize, grasp

Tags: difference, word-difference

Could somebody please explain to me what the differences between these words are? In which contexts should I use them?

Can I say that I grab a sandwich? Or that I grip a sandwich? (And eat it afterwards ...)
Can I grasp a sandwich??? (That sounds to me like I would try to "understand" it, but the verb "to grasp" can be used in that way, as well, no?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, in most day-to-day situations, we simply "hold" a sandwich, or "pick up" a sandwich. These words you're asking about are a bit colorful, and they normally imply some kind of extraordinarily strong grip.

"Snatch" means to grab something quickly, and perhaps steathily. I might say:

> *The homeless boy snatched a sandwich off the tray, and stuffed it into his pocket*.

"Grip" means to hold something in a way that would make it hard for something to come lose. Bread is generally too soft for a verb like *grip*, but I suppose I might say:

> *Having his first meal in three days, the prisoner gripped his sandwich greedily as he ate it*.

"Grab" is unusual, in that it has an informal definition, which NOAD defines as:

> **grab** (*v.*) `informal` obtain or get (something) quickly or opportunistically

So, I could see myself saying:

> I'm kind of hungry; I'll grab a sandwich before I come over tonight.

but, in that case, I'm not alluding to how I'm holding the sandwich – only that I'm going to get something that is *quick* and *convenient*. It implies I may buy the sandwich somewhere, or, if I'm making it myself, I might not put as much care into it as I would if I wanted to make something fancier or more delicious (for example, maybe I'll skip the mustard and just put the meat on plain bread).